# Will an Android 4.3 upgrade rewrite my custom /etc/gps.conf file?

Tags: gps, 4.3-jelly-bean

Will an Android 4.3 upgrade rewrite my custom `/etc/gps.conf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the upgrade to the android 4.3 did not replaced my custom `/etc/gps.conf` file.

It was edited by hands on rooted device before the Android upgrade and stayed with the same content afterwards.

<sup>Answering myself :)</sup>

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answer later. :)

Comment: Sure i will. Sorry for that mistakes in the language and thank you guys for keeping stackexchange clean and informative!

Comment: No worries. Glad you find this site clean, and useful, even though you fixed your own problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I flashed a modem (for my region) on my phone, I noticed that it changed the values set I via [FasterGPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fastergps); this app can edit the gps.conf.

So YES, chances are it will rewrite your gps.conf after you update. So, make a backup first.